# Change Text field of Material UI from black to white

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Hi so this looks simple but i haven't been able to find anything regarding this what i only want is for the following fields to look white:

[image]

To be specific the default labels and the border color. To further clarify i did manage to make the input text white itself by passing the class through InputProps. but am stuck with this. Please help me out here.

Comment: Can you add your current code to the question?

Comment: You have to make use of a ThemeProvider and add a theme object with your customization. https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/ 
We do not know anything about your implementation since you didn't share your code, so this is out of thin air.

Answer (score 3):

Ciao, to make the `border` color white you have to:

Define a `Theme` object in which you have to define a `primary` color and override the `MuiOutlinedInput` like this:

```
   const Theme = {
    palette: {
     primary: {
      contrastText: "#FFFFFF",
      dark: "#FFFFFF",
      main: "#FFFFFF",
      light: "#FFFFFF"
     }
   },
   overrides: {
    MuiOutlinedInput: {
      root: {
        position: "relative",
        "& $notchedOutline": {
          borderColor: "#FFFFFF"
        },
        "&:hover:not($disabled):not($focused):not($error) $notchedOutline": {
          borderColor: "#FFFFFF",
          "@media (hover: none)": {
            borderColor: "#FFFFFF"
          }
        },
        "&$focused $notchedOutline": {
          borderColor: "#FFFFFF",
          borderWidth: 1
        }
      }
     }
    }
   };
```

(I know, this will override all the MuiOutlinedInputs you will use in your project but I found only this way).

To pass this `Theme` to the `TextField`, you have to wrap it into a `ThemeProvider` and create a mui theme:

```
import { ThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
...
const theme = createMuiTheme(Theme);
...

return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <div class={classes.root}>
        <TextField />
        ....
     </ThemeProvider>
);
```

For the text color and the default label, you have to use `InputProps` and `InputLabelProps` with a `className` like:

```
<TextField
   variant="outlined"
   id="fullName"
   label="Username"
   InputProps={{
     className: classes.input
   }}
   InputLabelProps={{
     className: classes.input
   }}
 />
```

The css will be:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  input: {
    color: "white"
  }
}));
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-textfield-forked-yxrrj?file=/src/index.js:287-470) a codesandbox example.

Answer (score 1):

I think @evayly is right and you should use a theme provider (see his comment above). If you just need a quick hack for a one-off then the follow CSS seems to suffice. However I really don't recommend it for anything that is meant to last.

```
.MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline {
    border-color: white;
}
.MuiFormLabel-root {
    color: white;
}
.MuiInputBase-input {
    color: white;
}
```